# Windows Remote Viewing of Event Logs fails with "Access denied"

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to connect to a remote windows server (2019) from a machine in the same domain and view its event logs. However, I'm getting "Access denied" in almost all ways I've triied. Below is a list of relevant details:

- Event viewer's "Connect to another machine" works correctly
- PowerShell `Get-WinEvent` fails with Access denied (with proper `-Credential` passed)
- PowerShell `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTEventLogFile -ComputerName ... -Credential ...` fails with access denied
- after using winevt's [`EvtOpenSession`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtopensession), all subsequent calls fail with Access denied (which is epxected, as the check is lazily performed)

The following configuratons have been done:

- the user is a service account and has been added to the following groups: Distributed COM users, Event log readers, Performance Monitor Users, Remote Management users
- the firewall inbound rules to allow remote log management have been enabled
- in the WMI configuration management, the user has been added to the WMI root with "Remote enable" and all other permissions

So, the question being - what am I missing on order to get winevt `EvtOpenSession` to work, as well as (optionally) `Get-WinEvent` and `Get-WMIObject`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add more complex code examples of real `Get-WinEvent` and `Get-WmiObject` usage (**obfuscating private data**). Something like [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: There's literally nothing else than the private data in all of the above commands, they are straightforward - calling a command or method by passing server name and credentials.

Comment: When you say " a service account" do you mean a managed service account in the Active Directory?  Does it work if you add the account to the local administrators group on the target computer?

Comment: I pieced together a long answer here https://techblog.bozho.net/remote-log-collection-on-windows/